# I want to plot graphs dynamically comparing two graphs

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I am planning to retrieve live subscriber counts of youtubers and plot them against each other in a graph i.e. I want to see the change happen dynamically. Can someone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ... https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html ... https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/gallery/animation/basic_example.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this API to get the subscriber count of a youtube channel

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

For more detail [see here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true)

To get the live count you can hit this API in repeat after some seconds or minutes.

Then you can easily use the received numbers to show in the graphs